# Running storm from intellij nimbus error

Tags: apache-storm, nimbus

I am learning storm, and I made a simple project. I remember running it, and it worked as I can recall, but now when I try to run it from intellij I get a runtime error, can someone help me solve the problem? The error message:

```
25107 [main] ERROR o.a.s.d.nimbus - Error on initialization of server service-handler
java.lang.RuntimeException: Something wrong with network/dns config, host cant figure out its name
    at org.apache.storm.nimbus.NimbusInfo.fromConf(NimbusInfo.java:64) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$nimbus_data.invoke(nimbus.clj:169) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__7166$exec_fn__2466__auto____7167.invoke(nimbus.clj:1349) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__7166$service_handler__7410.doInvoke(nimbus.clj:1346) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.testing$mk_local_storm_cluster.doInvoke(testing.clj:151) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster$_init.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:31) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster.<init>(Unknown Source) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at stormtesting.App.main(App.java:20) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:?]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Manningers-MacBook-Pro-2.local: Manningers-MacBook-Pro-2.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1475) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.storm.nimbus.NimbusInfo.fromConf(NimbusInfo.java:54) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Manningers-MacBook-Pro-2.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1471) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.storm.nimbus.NimbusInfo.fromConf(NimbusInfo.java:54) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    ... 17 more
25131 [main] ERROR o.a.s.util - Halting process: ("Error on initialization")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error on initialization")
    at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__7166$service_handler__7410.doInvoke(nimbus.clj:1346) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.testing$mk_local_storm_cluster.doInvoke(testing.clj:151) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster$_init.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:31) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster.<init>(Unknown Source) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
    at stormtesting.App.main(App.java:20) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:?]
```

I just want to run it locally now until I develop the topology. Or is this a bad approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't resolve Manningers-MacBook-Pro-2.local . Add this in your /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 Manningers-MacBook-Pro-2.local

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Maybe could you explain why did it run previously some week ago when I tried it. What could have changed? But anyway thanks again for this help. I don't even understand how you can know this. :)

Comment: @mani in this exception "RuntimeException: Something wrong with network/dns config" it says there is a problem with dns and in this "UnknownHostException: Manningers-MacBook-Pro-2.local" it says can't resolve Manningers-MacBook-Pro-2.local. I don't know why it ran some week ago.

Comment: Oh I see, now I understand. Seems obvious now. Thanks